# R Euler Plot Basic Questions

Tags: r, eulerr

My question is about the inputs into library(eulerr) in r. I am trying to plot something I *think* would be simple but I am having trouble and it stems from my lack of knowledge of r and this library.

For this code :

```
fit1 <- euler(c("A" = 25, "B" = 5, "A&B" = 5))
plot(fit1)
```

I would think it would produce two circles with the following characteristics:

- Circle A would be large
- Circle B would be small
- **Circle B would be completely inside of A since they "share" all 5**

However, circle B is not entirely inside of A and I am not sure why. More to the point I would like to get my intended output which would be a figure that satisfied the three bullet points above. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To get more sense of the eulerr parameters you can check this [shiny app](https://eulerr.co). For the particular diagram you want to make you need to do:

```
fit1 <- euler(c("A" = 25, "B" = 0, "A&B" = 5))
plot(fit1)
```